# Using :even or filter(":even") in jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I am reading the jQuery API, about even selector, jQuery recommend we select a list of elements use pure CSS Selector and then use `filter(":even")` for better performance. But I think jQuery optimized for their `:even` selector too. When I used any selector, it gave me the same result with the same time. Will it have different only when we have more than 1 million of elements? 
Could someone please explain how the `:even` selector work and why use `filter(":even")` is better?

Thanks,
Tho Vo

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ Try: http://jsperf.com/filter-even

Answer (score 6):

Why not test it? http://jsperf.com/even-selector

If you're looking for something fast, use `:nth-child(even)`, as it's a native selector and can be fed into `document.querySelectorAll`. `:even` is a jQuery-specific pseudo-selector and forces jQuery to traverse the DOM using JavaScript, which will almost always be slower than `document.querySelector`.

Comment: :nth-child(even) is great,but is it sill good for IE lower version like IE8 as I knew IE8 doesn't support nth-child?

Comment: @Tuong: I don't have IE8 to test it out, but I think it'll still work.

Comment: I would've thought the last in this group would do better: http://jsperf.com/filter-even

Comment: Looks like `:nth-child(even)` is far and away the faster, especially with `document.querySelector`: http://jsperf.com/filter-even Unless it's used to pass context to jQuery.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: jQuery doesn't even come close to the native selectors: http://jsperf.com/even-selector/4

Comment: I know that. `:)` My question is why the context version is such a dog.

Comment: I see something wrong here,http://jsfiddle.net/sBh66/. When I use the nth-child, it just select the last p, not the first p, please check!

Comment: @Tuong: `.filter()` is causing problems. Change it into a selector string and it'll work.

Comment: @Tuong - `:nth-child()` appears to be indexed beginning at `1`, not `0`. http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sBh66/1/

Comment: The same here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5q6A/ when I use only the nth-child, not filter...

Comment: @Tuong - My last fiddle with `document.querySelector`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sBh66/2/ I'm not sure that `:nth-child` indexes are like that, but if so it means the first element is `1`, not `0`, hence the odd results. Or that jQuery indexes to an array, meaning *it's* off.

Comment: I see the nth-child cause more confusions than I thought,come back to use `filter(":even")` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can find performance tests [here](http://jsperf.com/even-vs-filter-even). As you can see in results filter('even') is faster though it will be noticeable only in big data.